# Missing component tab in blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4

I can't find the component tabs anymore. It shows here that the component tab is opening but actually it isn't. I've cleared all the window but this tick of components tab still exists. Now my code is broken and I can't link the new tank barrel to the Tank_BP blueprint class. What should I do? Try resetting layout and even reinstall Unreal but it still didn't work. Any help will be appreciated!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWMtw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are all actor blueprint editor view all the same as you described? Did the log report some errors about that?

I think maybe there is something wrong with your editor, several ways to solve youre problem:
+ If you are using the installed version(which is installed from Epic Games Launcher),just try to use verify to repair your editor.
[verify entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6ASk.png)

- If you are using the compiled version, just try to debug the blueprint editor module.